# Listen for all click event except when originating from inputs

Tags: jquery

I want to listen for every vclick event. So I have:

```
        $(document).on('vclick', function () {
            console.log('in vclick');
        });
```

But I actually only want to listen to vclick events that do not come from a text input. I could have an `if` statement in the handler checking where the event originated from, but is there a quick way of doing this with jquery?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click', 'input[type!=text]', function() {
        alert($(this).attr('type'));
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dg8zc/%20Fiddle)